# Upload file via FTP issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file via FTP with PHP. Here's my code, which is adapted from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php). The connection fails and I get `ftp_login(): Login incorrect` error. I know my credentials are correct, can anyone tell me what might be the issue or how I can debug it?

```
// FTP login details
$ftp_server='ftp.example.com'; 
$ftp_user_name='myuser'; 
$ftp_user_pass='mypw';
$file_path = '/filepath/';
$remote_file = $file_path.$remote_file;

// Create temporary file
$local_file=fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($local_file, $file_string);
rewind($local_file);       

// FTP connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// FTP login 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// Close FTP connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

// Close file handle
fclose($local_file);
```

Comment: I tend to believe the server's response. If it says "login incorrect", I would recheck the credentials (be sure not to include whitespaces etc)

Comment: You should check first if you are connecting ok, what is `$conn_id`?

Comment: While the error "login incorrect" should really answer your question, if you're 100% sure you have the username and password correct, make sure you have got the server address correct.

Comment: Thanks, yes the pw was indeed incorrect (sorry), but now I get an error: `ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path`. Is `fopen('php://temp', 'r+')` not a valid path?